# A word for someone who is overly cautious?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I am thinking along the lines of a hypochondriac, only not necessarily limited to health.

"Overly anxious" comes to mind but I don't think it fits exactly...

In context:

> 'I don't want to come across as being a XXXX but I am concerned that it will get damaged'

I need it to sound more formal than just slang.

Comment: @WillHunting added above

Comment: When I read your example sentence, the first words I thought of were "overly cautious." It's a [widespread](http://www.google.com/#q=%22overly+cautious%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=Ebk-UPPGIciuqAGut4HQDg&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAA&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1fdbf9716bd9b938&biw=1042&bih=753) term. Any reason why you don't want to go with the alternative in your title?

Comment: -1 shows no research effort, and close General Reference.

Comment: Some research has not thrown up any satisfactory answers yet. Maybe there's a point in the OP's question. Not voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Doomsayer** is a bit poetic/antiquated, but could pass in a "formal" context.

**Scaremonger** is just a little bit informal (but nothing like *wuss, wimp*, etc.)

If I didn't want to [push the envelope](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/push-the-envelope.html) with *doomsayer*, I'd probably use **pessimist, alarmist, fatalist**, dependant on exact context.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous slang terms for this including:

> nervous nellie
>
> wuss
>
> wimp
>
> chicken
>
> doormat
>
> handwringer
>
> worrywart

Answer (score 2):

A *worrier* is someone who worries a lot about bad things that might happen.