# What is a word to describe the character of someone who plans his actions in advance?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe some individuals who  cautiously  plan for the  future all the time.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. You might want to look at [synonyms for cautious](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cautious?&o=100074) and a [reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=phrcb&w=*%3Acautious+planning); and the tag wiki for [single-word-requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) about what your question should contain. Please feel free to edit your question to include the results of your own research, so that others don't repeat it.

Comment: Are you trying for a negative, positive, or neutral tone?

Comment: Also see LINKED section in sidebar  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178773) [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97456) [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102511) [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188124)

Comment: Related: [A word for someone who is overly cautious](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79983/a-word-for-someone-who-is-overly-cautious)

Answer (score 4):

In some occupations, “individuals who cautiously plan for the future all the time” are those who are *alive* or *uninjured* or *on time*, etc.  They may also be termed *[smart](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart#Adjective)* or *[sensible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensible#Adjective)*, but some may think them  *[fussy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fussy#Adjective)* (“Anxious or particular about petty details”).

More specific terms, perhaps pejorative, include *[calculating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calculating#Adjective)*, *[cunning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cunning)*,  *[scheming](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scheming)* (“Tending to scheme” – wiktionary), *[crafty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crafty#Adjective)*, *[Machiavellian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Machiavellian)* (“Attempting to achieve goals by cunning, scheming, and unscrupulous methods, especially in politics or in advancing one's career.”).

More neutral but still specific terms include  *[strategist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strategist)* (“Someone who devises strategies”) and  *[planner](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/planner#Noun)* (“One who plans”).

Positive and less specific are  *[prudent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prudent#Adjective)*, *[judicious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/judicious#Adjective)*, *[meticulous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meticulous#Adjective)*, *[astute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/astute#Adjective)*, and perhaps *[circumspect](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circumspect#Adjective)*. (All links: wiktionary)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply call such individuals *cautious*. You don't give any context in your question, but if you want to emphasize the planning ahead aspect, you could use *foresightful*, [defined](https://www.wordnik.com/words/foresight) by the American Heritage dictionary as (among other things):

> n. Care in providing for the future; prudence.

Another choice could be *forethoughtful* [defined](https://www.wordnik.com/words/forethought) by the same source as

> n. Preparation or thought for the future.

Answer (score 2):

If the characteristic in question is part of an overall personality where a person is very careful and deliberate, then I would use '[conscientious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness)' - one of the main Five Personality Traits.

"Conscientiousness is the personality trait of being thorough, careful, or vigilant. They exhibit a tendency to show self-discipline, act dutifully, and aim for achievement; **they display planned rather than spontaneous behavior**; and they are generally organized and dependable. It is manifested in characteristic behaviors such as being neat and systematic; also including such elements as carefulness, thoroughness, and **deliberation** (the tendency to think carefully before acting."

It is defined in the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscientious) as:

very careful about doing what you are supposed to do : concerned with doing something correctly, meticulous. Also: governed by or conforming to the dictates of conscience :  scrupulous.

Other words which might fit: [strategist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strategist) which means  "a person who is skilled in making plans for achieving a goal : someone who is good at forming strategies", [circumspect](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumspect) which means "thinking carefully about possible risks before doing or saying something" and [conservative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conservative) - "marked by moderation or caution".

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary says

> [premeditate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premeditate) to plan ahead of time

See also, *premeditated* murder.

Comment: To *noun-* this verb, it would be premediator. Which sounds funny to me...

Comment: @PatrickM you mean [premeditator](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/premeditator)? I can see your point.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that.... curse you, *fingers*! But if it's in a dictionary, I'm not making it up: have a well-earned +1.